# notepad++ how to split and copy values into new rows

Tags: notepad++

I have 1,2 ab on the first row and 8,9 cd on the second row.

I want it to be like this:
1 ab on the first row.
2 ab on the second.
8 cd on the third.
9 cd on the fourth.
how do I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you will need a scripting plug in. This kind of search/replace functionality is not built into Notepad++ -- you can't even really do it with regular expressions, because replacement values can't iterate through multiple captures (don't worry if that doesn't make sense to you). With a scripting plug-in, this stops being a Notepad++ question, and becomes a question about using the language. AND you will probably need to provide an example of how you tried to write the script.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how complicated your actual data is but something like this could work:

Regex find:

```
(\d+),(\d+)\s(\w{2})
```

Replace with:

```
$1 $3\r\n$2 $3
```

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ doesn't actually read the scripts, it only allows you to write them. You have to write it yourself. If it was in a language like PHP or JavaScript, you could use a `for` loop or similar to write the outcome to a variable to use, but that's about it. @Alan McBee's point about a plugin is good, but I haven't come across such a plugin yet. If there is one I would love to know. Also, a little more detail wouldn't hurt next time. Things like language, circumstances ect.
Thanks!